# Jasper-reports: Error: operator does not exist date = boolean

Tags: postgresql, jasper-reports, ireport

[EDIT: This problem was a result of  a bug within version 3.7.6]

The following postgresql query is returning an error:

```
operator does not exist date = boolean.
```

I can't figure out why. Here is the postgresql code that is giving me the error:

```
select
    c.source,
    s.name,
    s.grouping,
    s.kli,
    s.term_desc,
    (s.population - s.online) as non_hb_pop,
    s.online as hb_pop,
    s.population as full_pop,
    s.rep_date

from
    dwh.rpt_cu_private_kli_summary s, dwh.rpt_sgmt_clients c
where

    s.partner_id::integer = $P{rpt_cu}
    and s.rep_date = $P{rpt_date_beg}
    and s.userid=c.userid

group by
    c.source, s.term_desc, s.name, s.grouping, 
    s.population, s.online, s.kli, s.rep_date
order by
    s.grouping,
    full_pop desc,
    s.term_desc;
```

What does the above error message mean?

Comment: What is the purpose of `group by` ? I see no aggregates being used.

Comment: I was using aggregates before and then took them out without getting rid of the GROUP BY. Thank you for pointing that out to me!

Comment: Enable query logging and get the query as executed after parameter substitution out of the PostgreSQL logs. Post that. You'll need to include the following log lines that show the params, too. set log_statement='all', reload PostgreSQL, re-run your query, fish the query and params out of the logs, and paste it here.

Comment: Please post a _minimal_ query which gives you the error. Especially strip the `group by` and `order by` and - as far as possible - the `select` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the value for $P{rpt_date_beg} ? That's where things go wrong. Check the real query, might be in the errorlog, and do some debugging. Maybe some quotes ' are missing around the date value.

Comment: $P{rpt_date_beg} was set as 'Date' which is what it is in the postgres DB. The fields look like this 2012-01-16. Even though I received that error while inputing the query I still hit OK. Once I came back to edit the query the error was gone unless I typed something new. I'm not sure if it is a bug or not.